# sql order of nesting

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a clarification on this post:

[SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

In the accepted answer, the nested query is the one used for the max computation and the outer query joins to that. I tried to reverse the order but ran into a syntax error.

Query:

```
(SELECT id, MAX(rev) mrev
FROM docs 
GROUP BY id) b
join (select id, rev, content from docs) d
on b.id = d.id and d.rev = b.rev
```

There error I run into is this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'b join (select id, rev, content from docs) d on b.id = d.id and
>   d.rev = b.rev' at line 3

Does the order matter here?

Here is the link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/64570

Comment: It gives an error, did you try it?

Comment: How could I comment on your query if I hadn’t looked and tried to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that query like this.

```
SELECT d.*
FROM
(
  SELECT id, MAX(rev) AS maxrev
  FROM docs 
  GROUP BY id
) b
JOIN docs AS d
ON (b.id = d.id AND d.rev = b.maxrev)
```

Notice how it selects from a sub-query for the max rev.  While the sub-query is simply joined to the table.

Another way to write it :

```
select d.*
from docs d
join (
  select id, max(rev) maxrev
  from docs
  group by id
) b
on b.id = d.id and b.maxrev = d.rev
```

Or if you dare to use an EXISTS :

```
SELECT *
FROM docs AS d
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM docs AS b
  WHERE b.id = d.id 
  GROUP BY b.id
  HAVING d.rev = MAX(b.rev)
);
```

Comment: Thanks LukStorms, I know that. But I am trying to reverse the order. Do you know why my attempt does not work?

Comment: So you want the MIN instead of the MAX?

Comment: Check my sqlfiddle link and please explain why that query does not work.

Comment: It has 2 errors. 1) you start with a sub-query.  Instead of selecting from one. 2) the ON clause doesn't know a b.rev

Comment: I see that, so is it always true that subqeries need to be following onto a general select, in other words you cannot begin a query with a nested subquery? Can you please elaborate more on the second error?

Comment: If you watch what's in sub-query b of your SQL. It only outputs the fields id and mrev. So only b.id and b.mrev are known to the outer query.